# Aggregate from Data Frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R of the following form:

```
           City     Province   Poupulation
1       Bandung     JABAR       500,000
2      Surabaya     JATIM       600,000
3        Malang     JATIM       350,000
4         Bogor     JABAR       400,000
5      Semarang     JATENG      550,000
6       Cirebon     JABAR       300,000
7        Madiun     JATIM       200,000
8          Solo     JATENG      275,000
9         Tegal     JATENG      290,000
```

What is the necessary code to compute the overall population from city in JATENG province only?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega

Comment: Try `sum(df[df$Province=="JATENG","Poupulation"])` where `df` is your dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Province) %>% 
    summarise(sum(Poupulation))

#  Province      sum
#    <fctr>    <dbl>
#1    JABAR   700000
#2   JATENG  1115000
#3    JATIM  1150000
```

When you are only interested in the province JATENG, then this will do the job:

```
df %>% 
  filter(Province == "JATENG") %>% 
    summarise(sum = sum(Poupulation))
#      sum
#1 1115000
```

Perhaps you have to change the `summarise` function to `summarise(sum = sum(as.numeric(Poupulation)))`.